# Land use change evaluation using Molusce in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, molusce

When i upload my two raster files in Molusce (initial and final one) i get the message that the files have different geometry. 
Their coordiante system is the same as well as their tif size. 
In order to get these raster files, I have converted two vector files.
Vector file for the initial year is made out of classified polygons which have been done using an old aerial photo. Vector file for the final year is made out of classified polygons which have been done using google earth sattelite image.

Is it possible that the problem is slightly different shapes of the polygonized area?